# 'httpcontext does not contain a definition for current' ASP .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, ip

I have problem with this code below. Its say "httpcontext does not contain a definition for current".

public static string GetIpAddress()
{

```
string ipAddress;
try
{
    ipAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress) || (ipAddress.ToLower() == "unknown")|| ipAddress.Length>45)
        ipAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ipAddress = "Invalid IP:" + ex.Message;
}
return ipAddress;
```

}

I tried many way but not work. Please help me.

Comment: There is no static `HttpContext` in ASP.NET Core. You need to use `IHttpContextAccessor`.

Comment: Also, you might be interested in [`UseForwardedHeaders`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=linux-ubuntu#configure-a-reverse-proxy-server) if you're using a reverse proxy. If you're _not_ using a reverse proxy, then I'm not sure I'd be trusting `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` to contain a valid IP address from the client, as the client could simply spoof it.